# Importing django modules from java

Tags: java, python, django, jython

I am trying to call some classes from my django project using Java.
Here is my code:

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();

        PySystemState sys = Py.getSystemState(); 


        sys.path.append(new PyString("/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/"));
        sys.path.append(new PyString("/myApps/categoryApp/review/"));

        interpreter.exec("from products.models import Category");
```

But I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/myApps/categoryApp/review/products/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/exceptions.py", line 4, in <module>
    from functools import reduce
ImportError: cannot import name reduce
```

Any idea solving it?
I believe there is something wrong with the imports

Answer (score 1):

The standard version of Jython is compatible with Python 2.5. As described in the [documentation on running Django on Jython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/jython/), Django 1.5 only compatible in Python 2.6 upwards. You will need to run the 2.7 beta version of Jython, or the older 1.4 version of Django.